# Any way of accessing shape properties through a variable in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

Learning pygame, is there a more efficient way of accessing the parameters in this function?

`pygame.draw.circle(surface, "green", (100, 100), 20)`

For example, doing something along the lines this

```
circle =  pygame.draw.circle(surface, "green", (100, 100), 20)

circle.x +=10
```

I've done some google searches, but most problems weren't descriptive enough and didn't really provide the solutions I was looking for. I also tried my method above, but it doesn't end up drawing

Comment: `draw.circle` does not create a "circle" object.  Pygame does not have that concept.  It just draws a circle and forgets about it.  It does return the bounding rectangle, but if you need a circle object, then it's up to you to create the class and have it draw itself.

Answer (score 0):

In Pygame, `draw.circle` doesn't create anything, it just draws a circle. What you could do is define your own variables like this:

```
x = 100
y = 100
pygame.draw.circle(surface, "green", (x, y), 20)
x +=10
```

To redraw the circle after changing the position, just repeat the draw circle line of code

Answer (score 0):

[`pygame.draw.circle`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.circle) only drays a circle on the screen, but does not create a "circle shape object". See the documnetation:

> Returns: a rect bounding the changed pixels, if nothing is drawn the bounding rect's position will be the center parameter value (float values will be truncated) and its width and height will be 0

However you can create a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) with the bounds of the circle and use that to draw the ciicle:

```py
circle_rect = pygame.Rect(90, 90, 20, 20)


while run:
    # [...]

    pygame.draw.circle(surface, "green", circle_rect.center, circle_rect.width//2)
    circle_rect.x += 10
```

or even more simple using [`pygame.draw.ellipse`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.ellipse):

```py
circle_rect = pygame.Rect(90, 90, 20, 20)


while run:
    # [...]

    pygame.draw.ellipse(surface, "green", circle_rect)
    circle_rect.x += 10
```